# How to change line spacing in TextBlock

Tags: wpf

I am using WPF, there is a TextBlock in my UserControl. The Text is very long, so I wrap it with TextWrapping = Wrap. The question is, how can I change the line spacing?

The code is something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="abcdefghijklmn" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

The output is like:

```
abcdefghijk
lmn
```

What I want is:

```
abcdefghijk
<--increase this line spacing-->
lmn
```

Great Thanks.

Comment: You could use Glyphs as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/789c3e1b-e3ae-476f-b37f-d93ef6d0cb7b/)? Otherwise you could adapt the [Lineheight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.lineheight.aspx) and see if that works.

Answer (score 89):

Use `LineHeight` together with `LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"`

Like

```
<TextBlock Text="abcdefghijklmn" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="30"/>
```

(credz Mixer for the BlockLineHeight addition)

Comment: Only with LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"

Comment: This works in UWP as well